# Docker compose: run command variable substitution doesn't work

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

#### Problem

Substitution doesn't work for the build phase

#### Files

docker-compose.yml (only kibana part):

```
kibana:
        build:
            context: services/kibana
            args:
                KIBANA_VERSION: "${KIBANA_VERSION}"
        entrypoint: >
            /scripts/wait-for-it.sh elasticsearch:9200
            -s --timeout=${ELASTICSEARCH_INIT_TIMEOUT}
            -- /usr/local/bin/kibana-docker
        environment:
            ELASTICSEARCH_URL: http://elasticsearch:9200
        volumes:
            - ./scripts/wait-for-it.sh:/scripts/wait-for-it.sh
        ports:
            - "${KIBANA_HTTP_PORT}:5601"
        links:
            - elasticsearch
        depends_on:
            - elasticsearch
        networks:
            - frontend
            - backend
        restart: always
```

Dockerfile for the services/kibana:

```
ARG KIBANA_VERSION=6.2.3
FROM docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:${KIBANA_VERSION}

USER root
RUN yum install -y which && yum clean all

USER kibana

COPY kibana.yml /usr/share/kibana/config/kibana.yml
RUN ./bin/kibana-plugin install https://github.com/sivasamyk/logtrail/releases/download/v0.1.27/logtrail-${KIBANA_VERSION}-0.1.27.zip
COPY logtrail.json /usr/share/kibana/plugins/logtrail/logtrail.json

EXPOSE 5601
```

Env file (only kibana part):

```
KIBANA_VERSION=6.2.3
KIBANA_HTTP_PORT=5601
KIBANA_ELASTICSEARCH_HOST=elasticsearch
KIBANA_ELASTICSEARCH_PORT=9200
```

#### Actual output (Problem is here: substitution doesn't work)

```
#docker-compose up --force-recreate --build kibana

.........

Step 8/10 : RUN ./bin/kibana-plugin install https://github.com/sivasamyk/logtrail/releases/download/v0.1.27/logtrail-${KIBANA_VERSION}-0.1.27.zip
 ---> Running in d28b1dcb6348
Attempting to transfer from https://github.com/sivasamyk/logtrail/releases/download/v0.1.27/logtrail--0.1.27.zip
Attempting to transfer from https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/kibana-plugins/https://github.com/sivasamyk/logtrail/releases/download/v0.1.27/logtrail--0.1.27.zip/https://github.com/sivasamyk/logtrail/releases/download/v0.1.27/logtrail--0.1.27.zip-6.2.3.zip
Plugin installation was unsuccessful due to error "No valid url specified."
ERROR: Service 'kibana' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c ./bin/kibana-plugin install https://github.com/sivasamyk/logtrail/releases/download/v0.1.27/logtrail-${KIBANA_VERSION}-0.1.27.zip' returned a non-zero code: 70
```

#### Expected output (something similar):

```
Step 8/10 : RUN ./bin/kibana-plugin install https://github.com/sivasamyk/logtrail/releases/download/v0.1.27/logtrail-${KIBANA_VERSION}-0.1.27.zip
 ---> Running in d28b1dcb6348
Attempting to transfer from https://github.com/sivasamyk/logtrail/releases/download/v0.1.27/logtrail-6.2.3-0.1.27.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found answer after 5 min when I posted this question ... damn

The solution is stupid, but works: I only need to redefine args for the new user. See:

```
ARG KIBANA_VERSION=6.2.3
FROM docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:${KIBANA_VERSION}

USER root
RUN yum install -y which && yum clean all

USER kibana

ARG KIBANA_VERSION=${KIBANA_VERSION}

COPY kibana.yml /usr/share/kibana/config/kibana.yml
RUN ./bin/kibana-plugin install https://github.com/sivasamyk/logtrail/releases/download/v0.1.27/logtrail-${KIBANA_VERSION}-0.1.27.zip
COPY logtrail.json /usr/share/kibana/plugins/logtrail/logtrail.json

EXPOSE 5601
```

The solution is the following lines:

```
USER kibana

ARG KIBANA_VERSION=${KIBANA_VERSION}
```